# Abort a batch job in batch class got 'User must have modify all data permission' error

Tags: apex, batch, permissions

Abort a batch job in batch class got 'User must have modify all data permission' error, who can help, What user permissions or profiles are required to abort a batch job? Someone who can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message informs you, the "Modify All Data" checkbox must be checked in the user's profile or one of their permission sets.

This is not a permission that typical users should have as it enables a lot of other permissions too - see e.g. [About the 'Modify All Data' permission](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=What-does-the-Modify-All-Data-perm-actually-do-1326847422250&language=en_US&type=1). So typically best to get a user who is already a "System Administrator" to do the abort as they have the permission already.